# Weird syntax in C for function declaration

Tags: c, gcc

I've just met a weird-looking function declaration syntax in C, which is invalid in C++. It goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_func (foo)
     int foo;
{
    printf("my_func printf foo = %d\n", foo);
}

int main () {

    my_func(1089);

    return 0;
}
```

From what I could infer, it seems like it is a function definition, for which all parameters' types default to `int`, and if I replace `int foo;` by `float foo;`, I can change the argument's type.

But can anyone confirm that this is only what is happening, why does this syntax exit? Is it a relic from the past?
Why is it invalid when compiled with g++, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: That is old K&R syntax.

Comment: it's old K&R style. don't use that.

Comment: I was not planning on using it. I was merely "baffled" because it looked totally not semantically-valid. Sorry fro duplicate, I searched but did not really know what / how to search.

Why is it still valid?

Comment: @nschoe It's still "valid" because compilers have to handle legacy code. Code doesn't get rewritten just because the language standard changes.  And if you run into C code that uses K&R function definitions, do not add currently-correct function declarations/prototypes to the code base unless you also redefine the function.  A K&R function definition combined with a current-C-standard-compliant declaration/prototype is going to be badly broken.